# tsify - Only read browserify files

Tags: typescript, browserify, tsify

I am using `tsify` to build my TypeScript files. However, currently it seems `tsify` is reading all of the TypeScript files in my source instead of just the files included in my main TypeScript file (and subsequently imported files). How do I limit `tsify` to just the files given to `browserify`?

Gulp task:

```
gulp.task("build", function()
{
  return browserify({})
    .add("index.ts")
    .plugin(tsify)
    .transform("babelify", {
      "presets" : ["es2015", "stage-0"]
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source("index.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("www"));
});
```

And tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015",
      "es2016",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "es2015"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have `tsify` include only the files sourced from Browserify in the compilation, you should specify an empty `files` array in the `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015",
      "es2016",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "es2015"
  },
  "files": []
}
```

`tsify` will then include only the Browserify entry point files and their dependencies in the compilation.

If you are using other tools with your `tsconfig.json`, this can cause problems, as they won't know which files are involved in the compilation. If that's the case, you can either include the entry point files in the `tsconfig.json`, too, or can use a separate, differently named configuration file - e.g. `tsconfig-tsify.json` - for `tsify`. (You can specify a configuration file using `tsify`'s `project` option.)

Comment: This worked perfectly. It did mess with my code editor, so I had to use the separate configuration option. Thanks!